# How can i remove the autospace inserted by mobile keyboard words sugestions?

Tags: javascript

My input search when accessed in mobile insert a white space when user use suggested words of mobile keyboard.

Something like:

Word(whitespace)

The correct is:
Word(no whitespace)

I need remove this with JavaScript. I need remove the last whitespace on input and I don’t know create a trim in input box

Comment: Will you ever want/need a space character in your input field?

Comment: [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)

Comment: Yes! I want space in input, but like: how are you... but not how are you ...